# How do Programs interact with each other?

Tags: interaction, xbox-one

Okay so I have been doing a lot of web design and now I am starting to make standalone applications (at least I want to). Anyway, I am wondering how applications connect with other applications/games and how I could go about making one.

Here's an example:

Autobuyer is for Fifa 14 on multiple consoles. From this app on your pc you can buy and sell Fifa ultimate team players.

This question is a bit out of the ordinary but I just cant figure out is how they are getting the apps to interact with the game? Are they hacking/exploiting the servers or what?

Comment: The answer to this is a big fat "it depends". There may be official APIs, there may be documented or reverse-engineered data formats, or any number of things. Given that the difference between a "game" and an "application" means nothing to a computer, the question becomes "how do two programs talk to each other?".

Comment: @IMSoP I have heard of API's like Twitter's one but I don't think the likes of Fifa have API's and every day people are making Programs to interact

Comment: "and every day people are making Programs to interact" - yes, that's my point, there are many, many ways programs can interact. If your question is "how can I make a program which interacts with FIFA 14?", it is at least answerable, but could still do with a bit more detail of what you want to do, and what research you've done on your own. But if the question is "how do programs talk to each other?" then it's impossibly broad.

Comment: Even within the term "API", which you "don't think the likes of FIFA use", there are many different types of interaction - communication with a service over the internet, as in the Twitter example, is one type, but there are also APIs between different programs on the same PC (such as the Win32 API underpinning a lot of what happens in Windows), or between components which act like a single program but can be swapped out independently, and could therefore be customised without replacing the whole app.

Comment: @IMSoP Well what I really want to know is how do the bots work? like people make programs that get a bot to fill in forms to make hundrets of randomised accounts on twitter and I think they also may use them for Fifa

Comment: Again, there's not one mechanism used for both things. For instance, any form on a website can easily be automated, because the interaction between your browser and the web server (HTML & HTTP) is basically an API already. That's not really the case with desktop or console applications/games, which have direct access to the screen and keyboard/mouse/controller.